# After a trigger is executed on one table, is it possible to display the values of a column from another table? (PL/SQL)

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have a trigger that will execute when a table is updated. The trigger updates another table. I'd like to display the changes of the second table.

This is the code that I have:

```
create or replace trigger update_club_fee
after update of fee on sporting_clubs
for each row

begin

update club_membership set amount = (duration*:new.fee) where :old.club_id = :new.club_id;

dbms_output.put_line('Customer id is: '||:new.customer_id);
dbms_output.put_line('Previous amount was '||:old.amount);
dbms_output.put_line('New amount is '||:new.amount);
end;
```

Comment: Would it be hard for you to specify the table names? Instead of `another table`,`first table` and `a table`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a trigger is the appropriate tech solution.  The UI code that captures a change to club membership should propagate the changes to child tables and deliver any reporting.

But if you really need to use triggers, it's not going to be possible quite like that:

1. You cannot reference :old and :new on CLUB_MEMBERSHIP - these are
   records that relate only to the trigger's owning table
   (SPORTING_CLUBS in this case).  :old.amount will not resolve
2. An update on one row in SPORTING_CLUBS may result in many rows being
   updated in CLUB_MEMBERSHIP (each club has more than one member,
   right?).  I presume you would want to know about each row

I would write a procedure that accepts a club_id and a fee.  This will update all related rows in CLUB_MEMBERSHIP and then will also report on the updated rows.  Then call this procedure from your trigger.

But, please, don't use triggers for this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Christian Palmer about trigger use, but sometimes the trigger is a requirement from customer (yes, I had this requirement from one of my customers!) and you have to do it this way. Moreover, it's not always possible to add a procedure call inside a trigger (if the procedure references any table modified in the transaction you'll get an error calling it).

In those cases a possible solution is the following, using a cursor for looping on all members:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_CLUB_FEE
AFTER UPDATE OF FEE ON SPORTING_CLUBS
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

    FOR c IN (
        SELECT *
        FROM club_membership
        WHERE club_id = :old.club_id
    ) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Customer id is: '     || c.customer_id);
        dbms_output.put_line('Previous amount was ' || c.amount);
        dbms_output.put_line('New amount is '       || c.duration * :new.fee);
    END LOOP;

    UPDATE club_membership 
    SET amount = duration * :new.fee
    WHERE club_id = :old.club_id;

END;
```